# i18n easy way to render non-breaking hyphen

Tags: vue.js, localization, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm frequently translating `english` into other languages in my web apps and one thing I find quite annoying is the hyphen character `-` in words like `ready-to-use`. By default html splits the hyphen during a line break like so:

```
ready-

to-use
```

If I replace the hyphens with non-breaking hyphens (`&#8209;` ), i18n doesn't translate the character code:

```
ready&#8209;to&#8209;use
```

(this is not the actual translation, just to demonstrate the problem)

Another approach is to wrap it inside `<span style="white-space: nowrap"></span>` but `span` can't be translated by `i18n` either.

I am aware of an approach using `v-html` which brings security risks into the mix. How do you handle `hyphen` characters in paragraphs during translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some pain and with **tony's** help, I found a simple solution. `i18n` has [named interpolations](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#interpolations), which can be used to render a `html character code`.

```
{{ $t('message', {char: '&#8209;'}) }}
```

will render a `non-breaking hyphen` correctly inside `message` (`en.json`):

```
"message": "I am working full{char}time on this project."
```

**full-time** will suffer no line-break.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to use [the slot syntax of `vue-i18n`](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html#slots-syntax-usage):

1. In your i18n messages, extract the hyphenated word into its own string, replacing the original string section with a reference in curly brackets:

   ```js
   // i18n.js
   const messages = {
     en: {             
       status: 'My {readyToUse} card',
       readyToUse: 'ready-to-use',
     },    
     ru: {                            
       status: 'Моя {readyToUse} карта',
       readyToUse: 'готовая',
     },    
   }
   ```
2. Use the `<i18n-t>` tag in your template to render the target string with a [scoped slot](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots), using the slot name declared in the previous step. Inside the slot, render the hyphenated word (i.e., `$t('readyToUse')`) within a `<span>` that can be styled to disable word-wrapping when necessary:

   ```html
   <template>
     <i18n-t keypath="status" tag="p">
       <template v-slot:readyToUse>
         <span class="nowrap">{{ $t('readyToUse') }}</span>
       </template>
     </i18n-t>
   </template>

   <style scoped>
   .nowrap {
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   </style>
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-i18n-non-breaking-hyphen-quxl8z?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but does this not lead to splitting the paragraph into several translation functions? Before the span, the span itself and after the span. That is how I do it right now and depending on the language I have to `v-if` hide span elements. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way in `vue`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "translation functions". The string is rendered in multiple parts (as you described), where each part is clearly declared in the string in `i18n.js`. If you mean calls to `$t()`, then no, it doesn't require multiple calls.

Comment: The solution is indeed a bit complex, but I'm not aware of a simpler way. The good thing is this complexity can be encapsulated in a reusable component. See the linked demo.